# how to achieve backward compatibility with missing shared library

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I upgrade a program that needs to run on both old and new platform. In the new platform, I have new config so certain functions will not get called in the old platform. However, when I run the program on old platform, it complains missing shared library. What I need is something like "lazyload" or "delayload" mechanism such that when a function is not called the system won't bother to load its dependent library. But so far I haven't found a way to achieve it on Linux. I use gcc/c++ with normal link options.

I try simple approach of "-Wl,-z,nodefs" but with error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: -z nodefs ignored.
```

So how to enforce it?

Comment: `dlopen` and `dlsym`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, Can you check my new edits? Thank you!

Comment: It is `-z undefs` but it won't automagically create missing shared objects.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond, it is "nodefs" from the ld man page.

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your particular linker (you didn't specify which one, but we can guess it might be the default `ld.bfd` linker) does not support `-z nodefs`.  Try `--allow-shlib-undefined` to achieve the same result.

Comment: Sorry, I test it and it doesn't work, although it does not display any warning during link.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Instead of calling functions in the optional shared library as normal, call them via `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`.  This will let you explicitly load your shared library at runtime, when needed.
2. On the platform where the shared library is not available, make a dummy shared library and link that (or load it using `LD_PRELOAD`).  It will need to contain dummy versions of whatever functions your program calls, they don't need to do anything useful if you don't actually invoke them.

Comment: Thank you. Can you shed some light on why "-z nodefs" not working? It that works, it will serve my need (not perfect, but good enough for now).

Comment: Such wrapper library could be autogenerated via [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so) tool.

Comment: @yugr, I saw your previous post. It is good work and I like to use it. But to convince my coworkers to adopt it in our build system is some kind of hassle I like to avoid. Sorry for that.

Comment: @user3108468 lazy loading has to do with when the library is loaded into memory, and it does not disable the linker from trying to find the library to begin with.

Comment: @toppk it will disable linker from loading the library if none of its functions is called though which seems to be the OP's usecase ("when a function is not called the system won't bother to load its dependent library").

Comment: @user3108468 One option is to manually code such a wrapper yourself then.

Comment: @yugr the OP wants to be able to run without the library being available.  lazy loading (which is the default behavior) doesn't skip the resolving step where the linker/loader identifies the location of the library and suitability.   it just delays the moment of putting it into memory.

Comment: @toppk "which is the default behavior" - are you sure? To my knowledge lazy library loading is _not_ supported on Linux (not to mix with lazy _symbol binding_ which is supported and is indeed the default).

Comment: "lazy loading ... doesn't skip the resolving step where the linker/loader identifies the location of the library" - do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @yugr you are correct.  i was talking about lazy binding.